# TOC with (fake) chapter and (real) sections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I would like to have a table of contents displaying the sections from my document (`article` class) and some fake chapters (which I don't want to appear in the main document). I thought I would be able to say "I want only chapters and sections in ToC", and only have sections in the document, and add some fake chapters with `addcontentsline`.
I have tried this, but it fails (error message below mwe):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chapter name}
\section{one section}
foo
\section{another section}
bar

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
...
l.2 \contentsline {section}{one section}{1}{}

...
```

The error looks like there's a numbering issue.

I may be confused by the `tocdepth` or `secnumdepth`, or maybe there is another way to achieve what I'd like.

Comment: chapters are not set up, you probably want `\part`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`article` does not provide `\chapter` and therefore also not chapter entries to the TOC. If you don't want to use `part` instead of `chapter` as second argument of `\addcontentsline` you could use, e.g., [package `tocbasic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic) to define `chapter` entries:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry{tocline}{chapter}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chapter name}
\section{one section}
foo
\section{another section}
bar

\end{document}
```

[image: ToC with fake chapters]

Note: You can use the package also to reconfigure the `section` entries, e.g., to get a more hierarchical ToC:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=1em,beforeskip=0pt]{tocline}{section}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chapter name}
\section{one section}
foo
\section{another section}
bar

\end{document}
```

[image: hierarchical ToC]

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have paid more attention to the fact that there are no chapters with `article` class. I use part, and it's now OK!